# AWS - Start Wildfly server on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, wildfly

what is the right way to start wildFly server on EC2
I tried `sudo ./standalone.sh`  but sometime it closed

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `$WILDFLY_HOME/docs/contrib/scripts`.  You didn't indicate your specific Linux version but both CentOS 7+ and Ubuntu 15+ use [systemd](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-and-using-systemd/).  If you take a look at the contents of `$WILDFLY_HOME/docs/contrib/scripts/sytemd` the `README` goes through how to install Wildfly as a service that will run on boot:

**Create Wildfly User**

```
sudo groupadd -r wildfly
sudo useradd -r -g wildfly -d /opt/wildfly -s /sbin/nologin wildfly
```

**Extract and Install Wildfly**

```
sudo tar xvzf wildfly-18.0.1.Final.tar.gz -C /opt
sudo ln -s /opt/wildfly-18.0.1.Final /opt/wildfly
sudo chown -R wildfly:wildfly /opt/wildfly
```

**Configure systemd**

```
sudo mkdir /etc/wildfly
sudo cp wildfly.conf /etc/wildfly/
sudo cp wildfly.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo cp launch.sh /opt/wildfly/bin/
sudo chmod +x /opt/wildfly/bin/launch.sh
```

**Start Wildfly and enable it to be started at reboot**

```
sudo systemctl start wildfly.service
sudo systemctl enable wildfly.service
```

These instructions are for Wildfly 18.0.1 but just substitute the version of Wildfly you're running.

One thing that isn't very clear from these instructions is that if you need to run a script using `jboss-cli.sh` you'll need to run as the user `wildfly`.  One way to do that would be something like:

```
sudo -u wildfly /opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=/tmp/somefile.cli
```

Additionally, when you copy a file to `/opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments` it's ok if you used `sudo` for that as Wildfly only reads that file.